# How to check if all textboxes (including dynamically added) are empty or not?

Tags: javascript, textbox, dynamically-generated

In my form, onsubmit asks for return values form three different functions. One function should check whether the textboxes with a certain class are empty or not. In my form I can add textboxes with the same class as the one that already exixsts. When I add such a textbox, the function only seems to check the last added textbox because when I submit the form, it submits even when the first textbox is empty.

When I do not add any textboxes, the first one is checked... so the problem is only there when I add textboxes.

I would appreciate it when someone can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
            function legedienst()
            {
                var omschrijvingen = document.getElementsByClassName('omschrijving');
                var valid = true;

                for (var i=0; i < omschrijvingen.length; i++)
                {
                    if (omschrijvingen[i].value == '')
                    {
                        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Vul alle diensten in a.u.b.';
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }

                return valid;
            }
```

Here is the code that creates and deletes dynamic textboxes.
"bereken()" is just a function that is called to calculate some values.

```
        // dienst toevoegen
            var linenumber = 0;
            addLine = function()
            {
                linenumber++;
                $('#dienst').append('<tr><td><input name="dienstomschrijving[]" type="text" style="width: 200px;" class="omschrijving" /></td><td><input name="prijs" class="prijs" type="text" style="width: 100px;" /></td><td><input name="verwijder_dienst" type="button" value="Verwijder dienst" onclick="delLine(this)" /></td></tr>');
                bereken();
            }

        // dienst verwijderen
            delLine = function(line)
            {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            };
```

Comment: Getting the nodeList is live, and should contain the added elements, so I don't see how that would be an issue on submit? Something else must be going on.

Comment: is prototype.js kicking around anywhere? `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Can u share the code that creates dynamic textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery. Try this way.

```
function legedienst() {
  $('tr td. omschrijving').each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length==0){
      return false;
    }
  });
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function legedienst, for validating the textboxes having the class='omchrijving' is correct. In the delLine function change the "this" into "line", and it will also work.

```
$(line).closest('tr').remove();
```

I don't see what is wrong on your side. You can play with a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FkGb7/

Comment: I checked everything in your demo and I just can't get it to work... I changed the delLine function. I have no idea what is wrong and I don't have a lot of experience with javascript